# automatically login in windows authentication using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I've been trying to resolve this question for a couple weeks now via Google and reading SO, and not had much luck, so I thought I'd finally try asking myself.

I am setting up small web site application for my organization on our intranet to generate some information for internal users. I'm using Windows authentication,
and want to authenticate users automatically using their windows credentials.

Comment: I don't think so it can be done. As there is a security risk in it. Suppose I went some where without locking my computer then some one else can visit with my credentials which is wrong.

Comment: thanks can you share some examples.